# For a one-to-one relationship, how many fields should I join on?

Tags: sql, field, inner-join

I'm just curious as to what the convention is when writing an inner join. I want to join two tables that have multiple instances of match data. For example, 'hired date', 'employee number', and 'salary' are found in both tables. Should I join on all of these fields?

```
SELECT 
     a 
FROM 
     table.example a
          inner join table.example b ON a.date = b.date and a.id = b.id_num and a.salary = b.salary
```

Comment: Better to use employee id for the inner join as this is the key part to handle or relate other tables in this scenario specifically.

Comment: It 100% depends on your data, not any standards or anything and since we don't know your data, there is really no way to answer this question. Does it make sense to join on all of those columns?

Comment: You join by the fields that you intend to match on -- there is no way that someone else can define what you want to do.  You might consider deleting this question and asking another question with sample data and desired results.  Having duplicated columns across tables doesn't sound like a robust data model.

Comment: Could you post some sample data from both of the tables? And what your desired result should be. No need to delete this question. Just edit the question with more information and detail on exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of performance, usually you should join on the minimum amount of fields possible, preferably indexed fields

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to have join like this. Because you just create more redundancy.

1.You need to reduce your redundancy. It means if you stored your date and salary in table "B" you don't need to store them in table "A" again.

2.You need a unique value to relate 2nd table to the 1st table. for example in table "A" you create "id" as unique column and in table "B" you create "ta_id" that pointing to the table "A" id. then just join them like this:

```
SELECT table_a.*,table_b.salary,table_b.date
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b
ON table_a.id = table_b.ta_id
```